# Spinner android

Tags: android, spinner

soy nueva en esto, y necesito ayuda. Necesito pasar los datos que hayan sido marcados en los spinner(son 3), a la siguiente Activity,  lo hago mediante intent, pero no lo logro. El código es Java. Gracias

Comment: y dónde está el código?

Comment: Buenas, Ana, bienvenida al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Deberías editar tu pregunta e incluir la parte del código donde has intentado leer los datos de los spinners.